# How to split the table in php which is taking input from database?

Tags: php, html, sql

i want to split my table in two parts
i.e. 15 rows on each side. is that possible?
i have tried jquery too
still no use :(

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '', '', 'test');
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   

$sql="SELECT dateofattendance,timeofattendance, status,timeofdeparture FROM attendance Where emp='$name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);           
if ($result->num_rows > 0)         
{
    echo "<table class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th> Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tbody><tr class='warning'><td>" . $row["dateofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofdeparture"]. "</td><td>"  . $row["status"]."</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

Comment: your code is flawed, you're closing the table with every row. Is this a typo or is your code like this? Also I don't see any attempt here to split the table at 15 rows, just code to output it. Please show us what you have actually tried

Comment: @roryok , i want to display the output only.

Comment: The question is unclear - do you mean you want two columns, side by side, each with 15 rows?

Comment: Yes... I want two tables side by side.. Each displaying only 15 rows

Comment: What is your current output, and what is expected (can you provide some HTML for both?)

Comment: Actually my current output displays one table containing the data..  And my expected output is two tables. First table will display first 15 entries in the database  and second table will display next 15 entries.. Is that possible

Comment: my code is not working though. i mean when counter reaches to 15 it does not complete the table tag.

Comment: @Jaay I have provided the code above. i just want two tables to display my data one after another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you already have will output the data into a single table

```
if($counter<15)
{

    echo "<table id='my' class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th > Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>";             

    // This is the problem. The line below will not stop after 15 rows
    // it will run until all data is retrieved. Incrementing the counter
    // does not matter at this point because we're already inside the if statement
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        // this is also wrong. you are declaring a new tbody element for each row
        // tbody should be declared once, with the table declaration   
        echo "<tbody><tr class='warning'><td>" . $row["dateofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofdeparture"]. "</td><td>"  . $row["status"]."</td></tr></tbody>";               
    }
    echo "</table>";
    $counter++;
}
else
{
    // also you can't give both tables an id of 'my'. ids must be unique
    echo "<table id='my' class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th > Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th>                        </tr></thead>";             
    ...
}
```

The if statement needs to be inside the while statement. Try this code instead.

```
// create wrapper table
echo "<table><tbody><tr></td>";  

// create the opening table
echo "<table id='my1' style='float:left;' class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th> Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>";             

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    // create the row
    echo "<tr class='warning'><td>" . $row["dateofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofdeparture"]. "</td><td>"  . $row["status"]."</td></tr>"; 

    $counter++;  

    // when the counter is 15, close this table and open another
    if($counter == 15)
    {
        echo "</td><td>"; // move to the next cell in our wrap table
        echo "</tbody></table>";
        echo "<table id='my2' style='float:left;' class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th> Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>";  
    }            
}
// close the last table
echo "</tbody></table>";

// close our wrapper table
echo "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

This will output two tables of 15 rows each, which float beside each other

Comment: it worked.thanks.. but second table is displayed below the first table.. not on the right hand side

Comment: You could put the two tables within another table instead of using css. EDIT: just updated my answer with the code to do this

Answer (score 0):

wonder if this works

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)         
{
    echo "<table class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th> Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr class='warning'><td>" . $row["dateofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofdeparture"]. "</td><td>"  . $row["status"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within your first while condition that will parse all your fetched result, the second while is useless then.

Try to update your code with this, it may work

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)         
{          
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($counter == 14)
        {
            echo "</tbody></table>";  
        }
        else if($counter ==0 || $counter == 14)
        {
            echo "<table id='my' class='table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover'><thead> <tr><th > Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>";                    
        }        
            echo "<tr class='warning'><td>" . $row["dateofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofdeparture"]. "</td><td>"  . $row["status"]."</td></tr>";                    
        $counter++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```